# How to label features avoiding duplicate attributes and conditioning by two fields

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

In a layer with point geometry, I have the house number label. Each geometry has the HOUSENUM, PARCEL and STREET fields. In some cases the geometry is duplicated (equal geometry), in some cases the house number attribute could be also duplicated.

I am using the following expression to get the labels avoiding duplicates. But I need to be more precise and take into consideration the groupings by PARCEL and STREET. At the same time this function is not working well as it seems to duplicate labels in some cases.

```
array_to_string(string_to_array(aggregate(
  layer:='HOUSE',
  aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
  expression:="HOUSENUM",
  concatenator:='\n',
  filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)),',')
```

I am sending a screenshot of the result I am getting at the moment with the display of the attribute table for three different PARCELS, so that you can see the structure of the table and the duplicate values:

**PARCEL 00001 and STREET A and B**:
[image]

**PARCEL 00002 and STREET A**:
[image]

**PARCEL 00004 and STREET A and B and C**:
[image]

And I send screenshot of the expected result. I am interested in solving the conflict of duplicated geometries and filtering without duplicates the HOUSENUM texts according to the PARCEL and the STREET to which they belong. Regarding the Placement expected, just show the position to understand the problem.

[image]

Comment: Would cleaning up your data be an option? If not, how do you decide which feature to label?

Comment: In this case it is not an option since the layer with point geometry is generated from a table of full addresses table of municipalities. This duplicated geometry allows to run another expression to count how many addresses there are in a HOUSENUM

Comment: You appear to be asking two questions (removing duplicate labels and positioning the label next to the street). You will have to ask a new question for the second, else your question is likely to be closed for [needing more focus](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions#:~:text=Needs%20more%20focus%20%2D%20If%20your%20question%20has%20many%20valid%20answers%20(but%20no%20way%20to%20determine%20which%2C%20if%20any%2C%20are%20correct)%2C%20then%20it%20probably%20needs%20to%20be%20more%20focused%20to%20be%20successful%20in%20our%20format.).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent the duplicated labels, you can try this to render the label only once per `PARCEL|STREET` group.

```
case
    -- render the label for only the first feature of the group
    when $id = array_min(array_agg($id, group_by:="PARCEL"||'|'||"STREET"))
    then
        array_to_string(string_to_array(aggregate(
            layer:='HOUSE',
            aggregate:='concatenate_unique',
            expression:="HOUSENUM",
            concatenator:='\n',
            filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
        )),',')
end
```

Comment: This solution only partially solves the problem. There are PARCELS that have the same HOUSENUM for two different STREETS. For example, in this case the HOUSENUM '40' would have to appear twice, once for STREET A and once for STREET B

Comment: You can adapt the `group_by` parameter to include the street also. See my update. It concatenates the `PARCEL` with the `STREET` (separated by a `|` symbol)